# Refused to load the script in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, ionic-framework

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; 
style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I am developing android app in ionic and added this line of code in `index.html` when I added the whitelist plugin in my app.

Now, I get an error that says:

```
Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'".
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you checking in chrome browser?

Comment: In chrome browser white list plugin will throw this error, If you remove your meta tag security it will not show's the error

Comment: But anyway you should keep the security meta tag because we use Ionic framework to install mobile app's mostly

Comment: So, just wanted to check that this error is not going to give any problems, Right?

Comment: No it will not give any problem